# Split and format a CONCAT statement in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, opencart

Im working on a large OpenCart project. This is my first large PHP/MySQL MVC project and I'm a little confused. I have a MySQL query in my model code that returns a few things. I use CONCAT in the query to combine payment_address_1, payment_address_2, payment_city, payment_state, payment_zipcode. AS Address. The formatting sucks though and I would like to add spaces and commas where appropriate. How can I take the Address and split it back up with proper formatting?

In my controller Im not sure where I would add code and what would I add? I thought implode would do but I must be doing it wrong because its not working.
I thought about rewriting the query so it returns each part separately, but was wondering if there was another way!
Code from my controller:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['filter_address'])) {
            $filter_address = $this->request->get['filter_address'];
        } else {
            $filter_address = null;
        }
```

Comment: i would return each part separately and format it in php; there is only so much you can do in MySQL

Comment: All separate columns. I'm looking at changing the query but I use Address for filtering, and Pagination. I'm not sure how I could change this without having to change many other parts.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this approach strays from (part of) the point of MVC, the separation of concerns of the different components of your application.

The database should not need to be concerned with formatting the output. If you need to use the concatenated values for filtering and pagination as you mentioned in a comment, that's a separate issue, but there's no reason not to select the non-concatenated values as well, so you can pass them to a view (which *should* be responsible for formatting the output.)